# Html tags showing after ckeditor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ckeditor

Im using ckeditor CDN in my laravel project.I've got the editor to show up on the text area but after I submit the form,texts from the textarea displays along with html tags. Am i missing anything?

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <title>project title </title>
  </head>
```

Form view:

```
<div class="form-goup">
{!!Form::label('details','details')!!}
{!!Form::textarea('details',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

<script>
        ckeditor.replace( 'details' );
    </script>
```

show view:

```
{{$pages->details}}
```

output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtM9L.jpg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `{{ }}` syntax will escape the data with `htmlentities`.

For unescaped you can use `{!! !!}`

[Laravel Docs - Blade - Displaying Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data)

Answer (score 2):

This will display content with out html tags.

Use `{!!$pages->details!!}`

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 9 needs to use `html_entity_decode` method

```
{!!  html_entity_decode($description) !!}
```

in Older Version

```
{!!  $description !!}
```